# Last password change in macOS

Tags: macos, bash, user-account

Objective is to determine the last password change time for all the user accounts in macOS (Catalina).

1. `sudo dscl . -read Users/swastibhushandeb accountPolicyData`

> Output:

```
<dict>
    <key>creationTime</key>
    <real>1570887333.512722</real>
    <key>failedLoginCount</key>
    <integer>0</integer>
    <key>failedLoginTimestamp</key>
    <integer>0</integer>
    <key>passwordLastSetTime</key>
    <real>1570887334.500102</real>
</dict>
</plist>
```

2. `date -r` can be used to convert the epoch time stamps to human readable format as:

> `date -r 1570887334`

How can the above be wrapped in a  bash script/one liner code?Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
date -r $(sudo dscl . -read /Users/username accountPolicyData |
  tail -n +2 |
  plutil -extract passwordLastSetTime xml1 -o - -- - |
  sed -n "s/<real>\([0-9]*\).*/\1/p")
```

- `date -r <seconds>` takes some seconds.
- `$(…)` runs a command and captures stdout.

  - `sudo dscl . -read /Users/… accountPolicyData` returns accountPolicyData as XML.
  - `tail -n +2` drops the first line of the output of the previous command, because dscl prints some extra information before the plist starts.
  - `plutil -extract passwordLastSetTime xml1 -o - -- -`

    - `-extract passwordLastSetTime xml1` extracts the value for the key passwordLastSetTime in the input, outputting as xml
    - `-o -` outputs to stdout
    - `-- -` reads from stdin

      - `--` to stop parsing options
      - `-` for stdin
  - `sed -n "s/<real>\([0-9]*\).*/\1/p")` extracts just the integer from the output.

    - `-n` suppresses the default of printing every input line
    - `s/a/b/p` substitutes a for b, printing matching lines (overriding `-n` for individual lines)

      - `<real>` matches the start of the line containing the integer we want
      - `\(…\)` is a capturing group

        - `[0-9]*` matches digits any number of times
      - `.*` matches to the end of the line, thus removing content in the line we're not interested in
      - `\1` is the first capturing group
  - `|` pipes stdout from the left command into stdin of the right command

You can put this command all on one line if you prefer.

Comment: Thanks @grg.Any specific way to extract  multiple values ?

Comment: @swasti I'm not sure I understand, what values? There is only one passwordLastSetTime