# Convert passwordLastSetTime to date format YYYY-MM-DD

Tags: macos, terminal, command-line, bash, mdm

Trying to convert passwordLastSetTime to date format YYYY-MM-DD

The command is:   `dscl . read /Users/<username> | grep --context=3 passwordLastSetTime`

I want to convert this number to YYYY-MM-DD format. How would I go about doing that?

I also have this that I was using as well:

```
#!/bin/bash
currUser=$(ls -l /dev/console | awk '{print $3}')
lastset=$(date -r $(sudo dscl . -read /Users/"$currUser" accountPolicyData | tail -n +2 |
plutil -extract passwordLastSetTime xml1 -o - -- - |
sed -n "s/<real>\([0-9]*\).*/\1/p"))
echo "<result>$lastset</result>"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash
currUser=$(ls -l /dev/console | awk '{print $3}')
lastset=$(date -r $(sudo dscl . -read /Users/"$currUser" accountPolicyData | tail -n +2 |
plutil -extract passwordLastSetTime xml1 -o - -- - |
sed -n "s/<real>\([0-9]*\).*/\1/p") -I)
echo "<result>$lastset</result>"
```

This works thanks to the help from @grg

Answer (score 2):

### `date -r seconds -I`

`-I` outputs in `YYYY-MM-DD`. Add `-I` to the one-liner given in https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/421447/37797 which appears to be the core logic to your shell script.

`lastset=$(date -r $(sudo dscl . -read /Users/"$currUser" accountPolicyData | tail -n +2 |
plutil -extract passwordLastSetTime xml1 -o - -- - |
sed -n "s/<real>([0-9])./\1/p") -I)`

Comment: Was a small issue with the code you posted. Fixed it and got it to work! Thanks!

Comment: @MPL Great! What was the issue?

Comment: Posted below :)

Comment: @MPL Ah I couldn’t see what was different because I had `<real>` in my answer originally but it got stripped from output as a HTML tag, see Markdown source for edit