# Convert passwordLastSetTime to date format YYYY-MM-DD on macOS Monterey

Tags: macos, command-line, bash

The code below from [Convert passwordLastSetTime to date format YYYY-MM-DD](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/462563/convert-passwordlastsettime-to-date-format-yyyy-mm-dd/462568) works great on macOS Ventura machines to convert the date for when the password was last set on a user account. But when using on macOS Monterey machines it doesn't work. Anyone able to assist?

```
#!/bin/bash
currUser=$(ls -l /dev/console | awk '{print $3}')
lastset=$(date -r $(sudo dscl . -read /Users/"$currUser" accountPolicyData | tail -n +2 |
plutil -extract passwordLastSetTime xml1 -o - -- - |
sed -n "s/<real>\([0-9]*\).*/\1/p") -I)
echo "<result>$lastset</result>"
```

Comment: What exactly does not work? Do you get an error message (and if yes, what is it), is the result just wrong? Did you try to run the individual commands to see where it fails?

Comment: @nohillside The error and the resolution are apparent, but does this work on Ventura?

Comment: @MarcWilson I couldn't get it to work on Ventura, but I don't know what could be wrong in addition.

Comment: @nohillside The `-I` option to `date` requires a FMT specification because the value returned by `dscl` is in seconds, otherwise, you get an error, because the default is "date" format.  At least on Monterey.  I don't have a Ventura box to test there.

Comment: @MarcWilson Ah, right. The original version doesn't work for me in Ventura either.

Answer (score 1):

I removed the invocation of `sudo` because I don't see any reason it should be there.  Revision:

```
#!/bin/bash
currUser=$(ls -l /dev/console | awk '{print $3}')
lastset=$(date -r $(dscl . -read /Users/"$currUser" accountPolicyData | tail -n +2 |
plutil -extract passwordLastSetTime xml1 -o - -- - |
sed -n "s/<real>\([0-9]*\).*/\1/p") -Iseconds)
echo "<result>$lastset</result>"
```

The error that was being returned by `date` is obvious.  Apparently either Ventura has a different `date`, or the return from `dscl` is different.

```
$ bash testLastDate.sh 
<result>2022-10-30T19:09:44-07:00</result>
$
```

Edit: I also removed the attempt to parse `ls` with `awk` because it's silly.  That's what `whoami` is for.  You could also just reference `$USER`.

Leaving:

```
#!/bin/bash
lastset=$(date -r $(dscl . -read /Users/"$(whoami)" accountPolicyData | tail -n +2 |
plutil -extract passwordLastSetTime xml1 -o - -- - |
sed -n "s/<real>\([0-9]*\).*/\1/p") -Iseconds)
echo "<result>$lastset</result>"
```